# Multiple @foreach in views - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I need to output various `@foreach` loops throughout my blade template, however they all target the same table in my database, just fetching different fields. As an example, I am using @yield in my main layout and @section in the views for title/descriptions tags etc etc:

```
@section('title')

@foreach($store_listings as $fetch)
Website stores - {{ $fetch->city }}, {{ $fetch->country }}
@endforeach

@stop

@section('description')

@foreach($store_listings as $fetch)
List of Stores in {{ $fetch->city }}, {{ $fetch->country }}.
@endforeach

@stop
```

Then in layout.main:

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
```

and

```
<meta name="description" content="@yield('description')" />
```

This repeated @foreach loops are present in other sections of my views on other pages. I try to work by the DRY method. What are the suggestion here to save me entering multiple foreach loops when all I wish to do is call some variables? I don't want to have my controller to handle this business either.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do in this case it to use a partial, let's say `views/_partials/storeList.blade.php`:

```
@foreach($store_listings as $fetch)
   {{$title}} {{ $fetch->city }}, {{ $fetch->country }}
@endforeach
```

Then in your main view you just call it:

```
@include('_partials.storeList', array('title' => 'Website stores -'))

@include('_partials.storeList', array('title' => 'List of Stores in'))
```

Comment: Thanks, you've been a real help to me lately. Just to clarify, the name `_partials` is the name of the folder you are using as an example? or is underscore is relevant?

Comment: It's the name of the folder and it's just a convention, people use the underscore to remember those are not full views.

Comment: Isn't it about just writing fewer codes? Does it make any improvements in the performance? It still looks like it runs the foreach two times. @AntonioCarlosRibeiro Could you please help me to clear my confusion?